# Why SLF4J and Logback zero memory and computational overhead?

Tags: java, logback, slf4j

I've seen this over and over again. Why slf4j working with logback will involve **zero memory and computational overhead** even though it's a direct implementation?

> NATIVE IMPLEMENTATION There are also SLF4J bindings external to the SLF4J project, e.g. logback which implements SLF4J natively. Logback's ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger class is a direct implementation of SLF4J's org.slf4j.Logger interface. Thus, using SLF4J in conjunction with logback involves strictly **zero memory and computational overhead.**

**Updated: 2018-04-14**

With direct native implementation, there is no need for adapter which will require memory and conversion (there is the memory and computational overhead).

Comment: Same reason you don't have the overhead of a foreign-language interpreter when speaking to someone who speaks your same language.

Comment: @Kevin I got your point. But **Zero**, is this `literally` or `dramatically` saying it's zero overhead?

Comment: I think it would be literally zero, or at least as close to zero as makes no difference.  Have a look at [this diagram](https://www.slf4j.org/images/concrete-bindings.png) from the [SLF4J User manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) and notice how Logback classic fits in with SLF4J compared to other logging frameworks.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I read this but this time it gets across to me more clearly. With direct native implementation, there is no need for adapter which will require memory and conversion (computational overhead). Thank you, Kevin